# Keccak SHA-3-512: Missed a detail

Tags: c, sha-3, keccak

I just want to use SHA-3-512. So I used the [KeccakCodePackage](https://github.com/gvanas/KeccakCodePackage).

I read the [specification](https://keccak.team/keccak_specs_summary.html) and used them.To check my result I use the following [Online-Hash-Website](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha3_512.html).

My result for "Some Data" is:

> 15d7fb5fcb81cf8f178cd9ea946c298db9d6b3d3509a35d369fc58cbc923fab549df95dffddb371a5ef21745b3bf7f7a15ee7785a0ee81b97e9d87911e

While the Online-Converter returns the following:

> 15d7fb5fcb081cf80f178cd9ea946c298db9d6b3d3509a35d369fc58cbc923fab549df95dffd0db371a5ef210745b30b0f7f7a15ee7785a0ee81b97e9d87911e

I used the following configuration:

```
char* inputData = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
char* outputData = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);

inputData = "Some Data";
unsigned int rate = 576;
unsigned int capacity = 1024;
unsigned char suffix = 0x06;
unsigned int hashLength = 64;

int spongeResult = KeccakWidth1600_Sponge(rate, capacity , inputData, sizeof(inputData)+1, suffix , outputData, hashLength);
```

The complete code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/1fyJj52p).

The code that prints the value is:

```
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < hashLength; i++){
        printf("%x", *(outputData + i) & 0xff);
    }
```

I realized that there are more zeros within the other hash. So, my question: What is wrong in my code?

EDIT: Here's the entire program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "KeccakCodePackage/bin/generic64/libkeccak.a.headers/KeccakSpongeWidth1600.h"

void main(){
    printf("%s\n", "Run Keccak Test");
    char* inputData = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
    char* outputData = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);


    inputData = "Some Data";
    unsigned int rate = 576;
    unsigned int capacity = 1024;
    unsigned char suffix = 0x06;
    unsigned int hashLength = 64;

    printf("%s", "Hash the following data: \n");
    printf("%s\n", inputData);

    int spongeResult = KeccakWidth1600_Sponge(rate, capacity , inputData, sizeof(inputData)+1, suffix , outputData, hashLength);

    if(spongeResult == 1){
        printf("%s", "Sponge was not successful\n");
    }else{
        printf("%s", "Sponge successful\n");

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < hashLength; i++){
            printf("%x", *(outputData + i) & 0xff);
        }
    }

    printf("%s", "\nFinished Keccak test.\n");
}
```

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. If you have a textbook that tells you to use `void main()` in C, kindly fling it with great force against the nearest wall. Thank you. See also questions 11.12a and following in the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: `sizeof(inputData)+1` is the size of a pointer plus 1.  Is this what you want?

Comment: @chux Was tired, sizeof doesn't make sense at all :D strlen(inputData) is what I needed and wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you're printing the value.

```
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < hashLength; i++){
        printf("%x", *(outputData + i) & 0xff);
    }
```

The `%x` format will print a single hex digit for a value less than 16.  You need to print such values with a leading 0, using `%02x`.

Comment: That was too simple :D Thanks.